# Cognito User Pool Logs for SAML Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0, aws-userpools

I am using Cognito User Pool to integrate an external Identity Provider via SAML. I have two Idp's I am trying to setup. One is Azure AD, which is all set up and working fine. Another one is SecureAuth which is giving problems.

I am trying to find if Cognito logs anything. I looked in CloudWatch and CloudTrail. I dont see any logs related to his in both places. Where does Cognito log these errors? Do I need setup something for this to work?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm looking as well, and have no idea where to find them.